# Why is Java's GUI platform named "Swing?"

Tags: java, swing

Why is Java's GUI development platform named "Swing"?  What does it mean?

Comment: devalopers=developers (typo), do you mean 'Java Swing' ?

Answer (score 11):

[This](http://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/why_is_swing_called_swing) is all I've found so far - it's code name stuck and it was named after swing dancing.

Answer (score 4):

Many of the folks at Sun who worked on Java are into Swing music and Swing dancing.

Duke, the Java Mascot, was named after Duke Ellington, for example.

Answer (score 1):

> Swing is not an acronym. The name
>   represents the collaborative choice of
>   its designers when the project was
>   kicked off in late 1996. Swing is
>   actually part of a larger family of
>   Java products known as the Java
>   Foundation Classes ( JFC), which
>   incorporate many of the features of
>   Netscape's Internet Foundation Classes
>   (IFC), as well as design aspects from
>   IBM's Taligent division and Lighthouse
>   Design.

Found [here](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/156592455X/SWING-CH-1)

Here's [a history](http://www.mail-archive.com/jug-discussion@tucson-jug.org/msg00355.html) of "Swing"

Answer (score 1):

It actually comes from Swing dancing :)

https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/why_is_swing_called_swing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but **Swing** is name of the Java UI library and API. (The old, obsolete GUI is called AWT.)

Answer (score -2):

it stands for Something WINdowing Graphics.  Don't believe the heretics.  Nobody knows what the Something is.